# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or function, not undefined in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried checking other posts which stated that the same error message was seen, but none of them matched my context. I am new to ReactJS and I was working out on my own project. So, I created a two files 'index.html' and 'js/index.js'.

The 'index.html' file contains the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>-->
        <title>Profile</title>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">

        </div>
    </body>
    <script src = "js/index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</html>
```

And the 'js/index.js' file contains:

```
class Card extends React.component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="card">
            <div className="imagebox">
                   <img src = "2.jpg"/> 
            </div>
            <div className = "biobox">
                <p>Display Name</p>
                <p>Username</p>
                <p>Location</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Updates</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Card />, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I don't know what's wrong with this code that I am getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that the mistake is in the 'index.js' file. The code should have been:

```
class Card extends React.Component{}
```

Comment: Which is exactly what that duplicate says.  It was the first Google result for that error.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write a constructor?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```

And I think `React.component` should be `React.Component`. No?

Comment: as mentioned at
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor
no need to define the constructor js will do it by default
but thanks for the answer.